# sum case when with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find the amount of customers in specific segment
and the amount of customers that have valid mail or cellphone and specific brand from specific segment.

Tables are:

- "source" that holds customers+brands
- "customers" that holds customers, email, cellphone
- "segment" that holds email (that ref to customer)

I have some constrains: I build matrix query so I need to use the `case when` structure.

This is what I wrote - not good

```
SELECT
  count(*) as CountCustomers,
  sum(case when Customerid in
         (select distinct customerid from source
            where brand like '%abc%')
          and (Cellphone not in ('0' ,'-1') or email not like '%@NoEmail.com') 
        then 1 else 0 end
  ) as EmailOrSms
from customer 
where email in(select distinct email from segment where p=1)
```

My problem is in the case when I don't know how to write it correctly.

This is the error:

> "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

Hope you understand my question and could help me
thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can move the subquery to a left join, so there are no issues with aggregate clauses

```
select
count (*) as CountCustomers,
sum(case when source.customerid is null then 0 else 1 end) as EmailOrSms
from customer
left join source on source.customerid = customer.Customerid and brand like '%abc' 
    and (Cellphone not in ('0' ,'-1') or email not like '%@NoEmail.com') 
where email in(select distinct email from segment where p=1)
```

this is pseudo code, check the proper syntax

Answer (score 1):

Move that subquery to outer apply/left join

```
SELECT
  count(*) as CountCustomers,
  sum(case when s.customerid is not null
          and (Cellphone not in ('0' ,'-1') or email not like '%@NoEmail.com') 
        then 1 else 0 end
  ) as EmailOrSms
from customer c
left join (
   select distinct customerid 
   from source
   where brand like '%abc%'
) s on s.customerid = c.customerid
inner join (
   select distinct email 
   from segment where p=1
) g on g.email = c.email
```

Both distincts look ugly but perhaps scans are more suitable here than loops. And I don't like this join by email very much.